# Why do colors are whiter on Hololens 2 than in editor or captured footage?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

My problem is simply like the title mentionned, while on the hololens my app does not display the colors as they are in the editor. In the editor, they are as the image linked but at runtime with the headset, they white with
a small tint of blue. Even the captured footage with hololens show the color correctly, the bug only happens at runtime with the headset.

To have this style, I created a custom unlit shader with shader graph in which I get the position of the main light of the scene to calculate shadows and display them with lined textures. I added the an outline shader on top to finalize the effect.

On the device the lines and the outlines are displayed correctly it's only the tint of the mesh that is really whiter than expected.

Here's what I have tried so far and still have the same issue:
-Disabled the main light in the scene
-Reduced the intensity of the main light.
-I switch color space setting between Gamma and Linear.
-I tried other material using the MRTK standard shader (lit and unlit) and they were also whiter.

All my test were done with:
-2021.3.28f with URP.
-MRTK 2.8.3
-Hololens 2.0

Thanks for your help!

[In editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKAmW.png)